# Creating hebrew PDF files in .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext

I need to create a PDF file for my project using Windows Forms in C#, Visual Studio 2010.

I have done something with `iTextSharp`, but it only writes in English, and I need Hebrew using UTF-8.

Comment: Hi, Searching the internet shows lots of people have problem using unicode with iTextsharp, read this similar question hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042988/unicode-symbols-in-itextsharp

Comment: What problem are you having? iTextSharp absolutely support Hebrew and other RTL languages. Make sure that you are using a font that supports Hebrew characters like `Arial Unicode` or `Miriam`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pdf unicode with font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130470/pdf-unicode-with-font)

Comment: Similar: [Unicode Symbols in iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042988/unicode-symbols-in-itextsharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Docotic.Pdf Library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/). It shows Unicode text without a problem, see the corresponding [sample](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Text/Internationalization).

[Docotic.Pdf comes with free licenses](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/licenses/free)  for personal or otherwise non-commercial projects.

Comment: UPDATE:
Since February 15, 2012 we no longer offer free licenses for Docotic.Pdf library.