# Hebrew text in PDF

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext

I wrote a PDF document, and I try to write in Hebrew (UTF-8), and I can not in Windows Forms using C# and Visual Studio 2010 using the following code.

```
Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

//Create our file stream
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\moshe\\Desktop\\Test18.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
    //Bind PDF writer to document and stream
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, fs);

    //Open document for writing
    Doc.Open();

    //Add a page
    Doc.NewPage();

    //Full path to the Unicode Arial file
    string ARIALUNI_TFF = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\moshe\\Desktop\\proj\\gold\\fop\\gold", "ARIAL.TTF");

    //Create a base font object making sure to specify IDENTITY-H
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TFF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

    //Create a specific font object
    iTextSharp.text.Font f = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 12);

    //Write some text
    Doc.Add(new Phrase("מה קורה", f));

    //Write some more text
    Doc.Add(new Phrase("תודה לכולם", f));

    //Close the PDF
    Doc.Close();
```

I put the font in the folder.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a `PdfPTable`, then you can set the right-to-left mode:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

            //Create our file stream
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\moshe\Desktop\Test18.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            {
                //Bind PDF writer to document and stream
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc, fs);

                //Open document for writing
                Doc.Open();

                //Add a page
                Doc.NewPage();

                //Full path to the Arial file
                string ARIALUNI_TFF = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\moshe\Desktop\proj\gold\fop\gold", "ARIAL.TTF");

                //Create a base font object making sure to specify IDENTITY-H
                BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(ARIALUNI_TFF, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

                //Create a specific font object
                iTextSharp.text.Font f = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 12);

                //Use a table so that we can set the text direction
                PdfPTable T = new PdfPTable(1);
                //Hide the table border
                T.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
                //Set RTL mode
                T.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
                //Add our text
                T.AddCell(new Phrase("מה קורה", f));

                //Add table to document
                Doc.Add(T);

                //Close the PDF
                Doc.Close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mark Storer, I tried setting it on my `PdfWriter` object itself but it didn't seem to do anything, at least with a `Phrase` and a `Paragraph`.

Comment: Looking more at the docs for iText they say that the PdfWriter.SetRunDirection is just a placeholder method and that's what the source code for iTextSharp says, too.

Comment: And PdfWriter.getRunDirection() is never called in the source either.  ColumnText.get/setRunDirection is used, but that's an instance variable, and there's no way to set a default.  Gee, wouldn't it be swell if ColumnText grabbed its initial value from... oh... say... the PdfWriter?  I think I have a change to make.  Excuse me.

Comment: @Mark Storer, then is a table still the only way to write RTL?

Comment: Using a ColumnText directly and setting its runDirection will work, but that requires drawing to a PdfContentByte yourself rather than using the Element-based stuff added to a Document.  **Short Answer**: yeah, kinda.

Comment: Never did get that change in.  We're maven-ising iText and it's got my eclipse install all ass-over-elbows.  It's a pretty trivial change, I just want to be able to ACTUALLY BUILD THE THING before I check it in.  Grr.

Comment: @ChrisHaas the code does not work if I use a custom Urdu/Arabic font. It just does not display ANY text. My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609734/itextsharp-does-not-render-custom-urdu-font