# iTextSharp does not render Custom urdu font

Tags: c#, fonts, itext, arabic

I am using custom Urdu Font [Jameel Noori Nastaleeq](http://www.ffonts.net/Jameel-Noori-Nastaleeq.font.zip) with iTextSharp but it is not showing text at all. It shows text when I use built-in forms like times.ttf etc.

Code is given below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Document document = new Document();
            try
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\iTextSharpHelloworld.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create));
                document.Open();
                string fontpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\fonts\\Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf";
                //string fontpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\fonts\\times.ttf";
                BaseFont basefont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                iTextSharp.text.Font arabicFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(basefont, 24, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLUE);
                var el = new Chunk();
                iTextSharp.text.Font f2 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(basefont, el.Font.Size,
                el.Font.Style, el.Font.Color);
                el.Font = arabicFont;
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

                table.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;


                var str = "نام : ";
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(10, str, el.Font));
                table.AddCell(cell);

                document.Add(table);
                document.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Done");

            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                // this.Message = de.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(de.Message);
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ioe)
            {
                // this.Message = ioe.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(ioe.Message);
            }

            // step 5: we close the document
            document.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Update:** Setting `cell.ArabicOptions = ColumnText.DIGITS_EN2AN;` does render font in my desired font but does not any other text.

Comment: First, I must apologize because I'm not too familiar with any language except English. When I try using the font that you provided I also do not see anything but when I try some other fonts such as Tahoma or Courier I do see text in the PDF. When I analyze the raw PDF files, the characters are literally not included when I use your font. When I change the run direction I do see your font, however. This makes me believe that there's a problem with your specific font. For some reason iText isn't able to handle RTL with it. Unfortunately I don't know much about fonts so I can't help too much.

Comment: The question has been answered on the itext-questions mailing list: http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Issue-in-rendering-Custom-Urdu-Font-tt4657895.html#a4657907

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for your answer. Can HTML Worker thing help to sort it out? ABCPdf also can't see the font but when they use HTML code then I was able to see it. Is it possible I mention *font-family* in my HTML or CSS and iTextSharp can parse it?

Comment: Probably not. The fact that it works LTR but not RTL while other fonts do work makes me think that the problem is with iTextSharp and that specific font.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Jhon answered me here for the reason: http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Issue-in-rendering-Custom-Urdu-Font-tp4657895p4657940.html

Comment: check this question that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080741/convert-arabicunicode-content-html-or-xml-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Answer (score 0):

to write in Arabic I use the following font:

here is an example to create an Order in Arabic is the same for Urdu

```
BaseFont basefontArabic = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\\\windows\\\\fonts\\\\TIMES.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
iTextSharp.text.Font farabicNormal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(basefontArabic, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
iTextSharp.text.Font farabicBold = new iTextSharp.text.Font(basefontArabic, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);

 `Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                document.SetMargins(10f, 10f, 10f, 30f);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(FileName+ ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

                document.Open();

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5) { RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL, HeaderRows = 1 };
                table.SetWidths(new float[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 });

                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("الكمية", ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)) { GrayFill = 0.95f, HorizontalAlignment=Element.ALIGN_CENTER });
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("نوع السلعة", ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)) { GrayFill = 0.95f, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER });
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("الوزن الصافي", ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)) { GrayFill = 0.95f, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER });
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("س . ف", ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)) { GrayFill = 0.95f, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER });
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("الجملة", ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)) { GrayFill = 0.95f, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER });

                foreach (OrderDetailsEntity item in Order.Details)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.Quantité.ToString("N3"), ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)));
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.ArticleLigneFacture.Désignation, ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)));
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.QantitéEmballage.ToString("N3"), ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)));
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.PrixAchatUnitaire.ToString("N3"), ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)));
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.TotalLigneFacture.ToString("N3"), ReportDesigner.farabicNormal)));
                }
document.Add(table);
                document.Close();`
```

[image: OutPut]

Comment: It does not work for custom Urdu font like *Jameel Nastaleeq* or other *Nastaleeq* fonts