# Checkbox character in iText

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to insert a checkbox character into my pdf like this :

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("\u2610 somemoretext", somefont);
```

The "somemoretext"-portion of the String is beeing displayed correctly, the checkbox character isn´t. Do i have to use something specific as a Font for this character, or what else could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a font and encoding that contains those characters. Your best bet is to use IDENTITY_H for your encoding, as this grants you access to every character within a given font:

`Font font = FontFactory.getFont(f.getName(),BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);`

but you still have to use the right font. [This](http://www.itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=11) link could prove to be of help to you too

EDIT:

I also see different `Font`s use different conversion codes/sequences:

> Use a corresponding character in a different font.  For instance in
>   Wingdings.ttf you have 0x6F and 0x70

Comment: @sMaN As per the docs the first parameter is a `String` which is the name of the Font Family i.e `getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA,13)` where `FontFactory.HELVETICA` is the font families name and 13 is the size of the font. Read the docs they ill help you understand the necessary parameters of methods etc. Another example is `FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 8, Font.ITALIC)`

Comment: So in the given example, the variable 'f' is an instance of Font, therefor f.getName() returns the string representation of the font name. I just couldn't see the variable f defined or instanciated anywhere in the examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var font = FontFactory.GetFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\wingding.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, true, 12);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("\xFC somemoretext", font);
```

Inspired by
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5044017/1021364

Character map

[image]

check: FB

tick: FC

check in checkbox: FD

tick in checkbox: FE

empty checkbox: 6F

Comment: While the op did not mention that he works on windows and, therefore, WinDings are  not necessarily available, the generalised  tip to look for a font containing the desired characters is applicable.